# Unable to remote connect VisualVM to CentOS

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm

I am new to VisualVM and trying to monitor some application which is deployed on Tomcat 9 CentOS server. I have installed VisualVM on my Windows laptop and trying to remote connect to the JVM on the CentOS server, but nothing is displayed (message on VisualVM: Not supported for this JVM).

Please find below Java version installed on CentOS server:

```
[root@localhost bin]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Based on the online resource I saw, I need to enable JMX on Tomcat, so I have added the following properties in my setenv.sh (in tomcat/bin folder) file:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

I have downloaded the latest VisualVM and created a remote host via File->Add Remote Host. Then Add JMX Connection info as follows:

```
connection:dymmyip:8999
username  :user
Password  :dummyPassword
uncheck   :do not require ssl
```

When I try to connect, the following screen is displayed:

[image]

Can anyone tell me please what I am missing here?

Comment: ```connection:dymmyip:8081``` should be ```connection:dymmyip:8999```. 8081 is the http port of the tomcat. 8999 is port used for JMX connection.

Comment: @StéphaneMillien I have updated the port but still same issue. I have also edited my question to show the port 8999 in my screenshot

Comment: Both screenshots are the same, and the first screenshot does not show the information it should contain according to the paragraph before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the missing `=true` in your `setenv.sh`

```sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
```

You have to `chmod` you `setenv.sh` too:

```sh
$ cd <your-tomcat-dir>/bin
$ chmod a+x setenv.sh
```

Be sure it is not a firewall issue. Test the connection with `telnet dummyip 8999`

Be sure using the same JVM on both VisualVM and Tomcat. (Be careful with architecture too: 32 or 64bits)

You can get the last release of `VisualVM` [here](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html).
To install it:

```sh
$ [ -f "/usr/bin/visualvm" ] && sudo mv /usr/bin/visualvm{,.old}
$ wget https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/releases/download/2.1.4/visualvm_214.zip
$ unzip visualvm_214.zip
$ sudo mv visualvm_214 /opt/
$ sudo ln -s /opt/visualvm_214/bin/visualvm /usr/bin/

$ visualvm --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
```

Use the path you want in `--jdkhome`.

Comment: Thnks I have added the config "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true"  I can telnet successfully from my from my laptop but same issue when visualVM connecting to the remote server

Comment: You have set `authenticate=false`. Try without username and password in visualvm.

Comment: I have edited my response and add "...local.only=false". Check the JVM you use on the both side too.